# Too large cache causes disks to grind, I/O to drop

Tags: cache, storage

This is a followup question to [my earlier problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94079/13922). In short I was experiencing massive I/O drops together with not-so-violent disk grinding, and with help I found out that the big caches were the problem. Now I'm trying to find a solution to it.

I'm running a daily updated 32bit Debian testing on a computer with 16GB RAM, 120GB SSD and two 1TB HDDs. SSD stores read-heavy of the distribution and one of the 1TB disks store /var /tmp /media and other write heavy parts including a part of my home folder. 2nd HDD is a pure file storage. Everything is EXT4 formatted.

The distribution's nominal RAM usage is 1 to 1.5GB. Remaining RAM is converted to cache at kernel's discretion. After cache grows beyond a point, I/O performance drops massively (from ~90MB/sec to ~5MB/sec). Dropping caches solves the problem but only temporarily.

What can be the reason? While I'm a developer and a former cluster admin, caching is beyond my knowledge at this point.

Comment: 32bit System with 16GB RAM?

Comment: Yes. I've just transferred the disks to the new system. Since system has PAE support, detecting and using it is not a problem.